# How can I figure out why elpy-doc fails to find documentation?

Tags: elpy

I have Elpy version 1.35.0 in Emacs 28.2. I'm trying to use `elpy-doc` on functions in modules that my Python program imports. I know that the functions have docstrings (because I wrote those modules), but `elpy-doc` returns empty results for them.

**How can I debug why `elpy-doc` is failing?** I would normally use `edebug-defun` and trace through functions in Emacs until I figure out what's happening, but Elpy uses a Python backend via some RPC mechanism, and I haven't figured out how to put a breakpoint into the docstring function that gets invoked.

Comment: Does it work for built-in python functions?

Comment: @NickD It does seem to work on built-in and functions from common Python packages (e.g., `sys`)

Comment: My guess then is that it needs some configuration to tell it where to look for other packages. But beware: it's really a guess - I don't know much about it.

Comment: elpy is only as smart as it's backend (Jedi). if the backend can't figure it out then elpy cant display it